# Enable hirb print for array

Tags: ruby, hirb

In [hirb tutorial](http://tagaholic.me/hirb/doc/classes/Hirb/Helpers/Table.html) there's an example for array:

```
[[1,2], [2,3]]
```

prints as

```
+---+---+
| 0 | 1 |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
+---+---+
```

But I can't make it work after usual setting up:

```
require 'hirb'
=>true
>> Hirb.enable
=>nil
```

The arrays are still printed in usuall manner.

What does it require to print an array as a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'hirb'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Hirb.enable :output=>{"Array"=>{:class=>Hirb::Helpers::Table}}
=> true
irb(main):003:0> [[1,2], [2,3]]
+---+---+
| 0 | 1 |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
+---+---+
2 rows in set
```

Comment: Is it possible to call render implicitly?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the above, this works well also, via github user: pjb3

add this to your gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'hirb'
end
```

Run bundle to get the gem:

```
$ bundle
```

Modify your ~/.irbrc to enable HIRB:

```
$ echo 'begin; require "hirb"; Hirb::View.enable; rescue; end' >> ~/.irbrc
```